# ADO.NET Entity data model creation problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I can not create ADO.NET Entity data model. The following error occurs:

> An error occured Loading the entity
>   data model tool package. Failed to
>   load entity data model tools package.
>   The result is -2147024891.

I don't know why this happened.But i noticed this problem occurred after installing the asp.net ajax control tool kit beta. I uninstalled visual studio 2008 and sql server 2005 from the control panel selecting each component. And then installed them again. But the problem is  still here :(

Please any body help.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the asp.net ajax control tool kit beta?

Comment: yes, I uninstalled the whole visual studio 2008. And then reinstalled it. But the ajax control tool kit was still there!! I dont know how to remove it.

Comment: Well i found the solve. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some of these [workarounds via Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362602) will help you.

Comment: Yes this is the exact solution for this problem. Though i have found it before.. I mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

from the microsoft connect workarounds : [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/362602/an-error-occured-loading-the-entity-data-model-tools-package)

> Failed to load entity data model tools
>   package. The result is -2147467259. "
>
> finally found a solution:
>
> 1. To delete "C: \ Program Files \ Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 \
>      Common7 \ IDE \ ItemTemplatesCache \
>      CSharp \ Data \ 1033" the following
>      documents
>      AdoNetEntityDataModelCSharp.zip. This
>      is a template Ado.net Entity Model,
>      1033 is the English version and
>      Chinese version for 2052.
> 2. Open CMD.exe as Administrator go to  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE" or what ever your instalation folder is.
>
> Run the command "devenv /Setup".

In my case there were no output on cmd that operation was successfully completed. But it was.